# Perl conditional substitution

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I have a pathname with placeholders in it which i want to substitute:

```perl
# an example path with a placeholder
my $path = '%myproject%Web/ui/images/';

# mapping of all placeholders   
my %placeholders = (
  myproject => 'myproject/installation/all'
);

# substituting all placeholders in the path
$path =~ s!%(.*?)%!/$placeholders{$1}/!g;

# works fine -> 'myproject/installation/all/Web/ui/images/'
print $path;
```

This code works fine, but has one problem: I have a long list of filesnames and different placeholders specified (hence the hash). Now for the sake of more robustness I'd like to throw an error if there is a placeholder specified in the path which does not exist in the `%placeholders` mapping.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now for the sake of more robustness I'd like to throw an error if there is a placeholder specified in the path which does not exist in the %placeholders mapping

This can be done very easily using `/e`:

```
$path =~ s{%([^%]+)%}{
   exists($path{$1})
      ? '/'.$path{$1}.'/'
      : die "Placeholder $1 does not exist"
}ge;
```

Note: I think it's good to replace `.*?` with `[^%]+` to prevent incorrect matching.

Comment: In this use case, a simple test for definedness might be enough, as it is an error to include an existing but undefined value in a string. This would simplify the substitution code to `$path{$1} // die ...`

Comment: @amon Its test for defined, not exists. But yes, i think its possible. But he did not say what Perl version he had, since `//` is relatively new operator.

Comment: @amon thank you both for your excellent and fast replies. amons version works just fine for my perl 5.12. One problem though: I have `/$path{$1}/` <- these enclosing `/` need to be there too.

Comment: @Christoph fixed answ for this, seems its not possible with `//` operator

Comment: sure, that was an easy one with the ternary operator, doesn't work with the definedness operator though? I'd prefer this for it's compactness.

Comment: @Christoph I'd prefer too and i actively used it on previous work, but on current work we have perl 5.8.8 and its not working.. Sure its better in simple cases, but less portable and not so flexible as in this case with enclosing `/`

Answer (score 1):

Using `given` allows this, but it's a lot longer than it could be if a statement modifier form of `given` was available.

```
use v5.10;;
use warnings;

my $path = '%myproject%Web/ui/images/'; 

my %placeholders = (
  myproject => 'myproject/installation/all'
);

$path =~ s!%(\w+)%!given ($placeholders{$1} // die qq(Invalid placeholder "$1")) { "/$_/" }!ge;

print $path;
```